# Is the intersection of connected spaces also connected, when it is not empty?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B$ be two connected spaces such that the intersection is not empty.

I was able to show that the union $A\cup B$ is connected under these hypotheses.

Is the intersection  $A \cap B$ also connected?

Comment: No, take a circle. Let $A$ be the upper half arc, and $B$ the lower half arc. These are both connected, and their intersection is two points, which is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks I already make the proof that A union B is connected space with the same hypothesis...but I try to do the same proof now I understand where is my mistake thank you !

Answer (score 5):

$$\huge\between$$

$\qquad\qquad$

Comment: thanks ! I see it sometime it's just to easy and I search for more !

Comment: @jenny: You’re welcome! (I think that we all have that problem from time to time.)

Comment: I have a similar question with A a subset of B and B a subset of C, with A and C connected. Does B is a connected space ? my answer is NO  A = [0,1]    B= [0,3) union {4}     C= [0,4]  I'm okay with that ?

Comment: @jenny: Yes, that’s a fine counterexample.

Comment: thanks you its appreciate sorry for my english I'm french ;)

Comment: @jenny: À votre service! (But my French is worse than your English; my German is much better.)